# How to form a subquery

Tags: mysql

I think I need a subquery for this, and while I have read *what* subqueries are, I have not found help on *how* to write a subquery. I am interested in learning how to fish, but I also would like a fish soon, please :)

Simple, 1 table of data:
lastname, (found or not found boolean)

I want to generate some stats, across the whole alphabet, of who has been found.

```
Desired results:
A : 5 of 16 found, or about 31 percent
B : 2 of 4 found, or about 50 percent
C : 30 of 90 found, or about 30 percent
etc
```

I can form simple SQL, I need help with forming the subquery, if that's what is needed here.

I can write a query to list how many were found by the first letter of the last name:

```
select substring(lastname,1,1) as lastinitial, count(*) from members where found !=0 and found is not null group by lastinitial;
```

I can write a query to list how many total there are, by last initial:

```
select substring(lastname,1,1) as lastinitial, count(*) from members group by lastinitial;
```

But how do I combine the two queries to yield the desired result? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't need sub-query for this. The grouping can give you both found and not found for each name. Just add "found" to the grouping and you will get two records for each name, one for found and another for not found. You also don't need another query for the total, just add the found and not found together.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(lastname,1,1) AS lastinitial,
       (CASE WHEN found = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS found_val,
       COUNT(lastname) AS found_count
FROM members
GROUP BY lastinitial, found_val;
```

If you want to have both of the found and not found in one row for each letter, try this:

```
SELECT found_list.lastinitial, found_count, not_found_count
FROM (
    SELECT SUBSTRING(lastname,1,1) AS lastinitial, COUNT(lastname) AS found_count
    FROM members
    WHERE found = 1
    GROUP BY lastinitial
) AS found_list,
(
    SELECT SUBSTRING(lastname,1,1) AS lastinitial, COUNT(lastname) AS not_found_count
    FROM members
    WHERE found IS NULL OR found = 0
    GROUP BY lastinitial
) AS not_found_list
WHERE found_list.lastinitial = not_found_list.lastinitial
```

As you can see, the first query is much shorter, more elegant, and also performs faster.

Comment: Thanks @Racil, it's close! You've introduced the CASE operation to provide a count of 0 for a not found. The query above produced this from my data, so it's close, but not done yet.: +-------------+-----------+-------------+
| lastinitial | found_val | found_count |
+-------------+-----------+-------------+
| A           |      NULL |           0 |
| A           |         0 |          13 |
| B           |      NULL |           0 |
| B           |         0 |          46 | there is no accounting yet for found/not found in the result.

Comment: @user3395961 Oh, I must have been asleep when I posted the answer. I've corrected it. Please try it now.

Comment: Well, we are definitely finding the right things to count, and we are counting them the right way, but the result still produces 2 rows per letter (not desired), and no ratio. The magic apparently is getting the found_val and a total in 1 row so the division can be done. Thank you for your continued help
+-------------+-----------+-------------+
| lastinitial | found_val | found_count |
+-------------+-----------+-------------+
| A           |         0 |          13 |
| A           |         1 |           5 |
| B           |         0 |          46 |
| B           |         1 |          18 |

Comment: But that's what I said in my answer. It gives two rows per letter, one for found and another for not found. I assume you run this query in an application so you get the results there and loop through the record to combine the rows and calculate the total & percentage. If you want it all in SQL then you probably have to use sub-queries. I can add that to my answer as an alternative, if you want.

Comment: Great. Thank you! This is good enough for my work now. I definitely learned more about SQL - I think subquery is the way to go for this project, for this query. If you have any more cycles, I still can't figure out how to do the percentages on the same row.